# Unable to find JSON path nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, path

I'm not able to edit my 'translateTo' value ive been looking for hours

ive tried several things to target it but none worked

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileName = './data/events.json';
var file = require(fileName);

file.translateTo = "new value";

fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(file), function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
  console.log('writing to ' + fileName);
});
```

Nothing changes in my json file. 
I need the 'translateTo' to get a value. 
Maybe one of you could help me?

https://ghostbin.com/paste/eo9dj This is the json file

Comment: It's not clear to me what your issue is. What do you mean with "target my ... object"? *"I need the 'translateTo' to get a value"* Are you saying that the property `translateTo` doesn't exist on `file` after you assign it? How does the title of your question related to the problem?

Comment: TranslateTo does exist i want to edit the value of it trough nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You have to access "translateTo" by `file[1].actions[2].translateTo` instead of `file.translateTo`.

By the way, require is a synchronous function which blocks I/O. I would consider using `fs` instead.